# Can I use the NRF24L01 in a vacuum?

Tags: arduino, nrf24l01, vacuum, harsh-environment

Can I use the NRF24L01 module in a vacuum chamber?

I want to put sensors in the chamber, connect them to an Arduino with an NRF24L01 module, and transmit data. Will the module work in metal and glass vacuum chambers?

Can data transmit through the vacuum chamber, considering it's a confined space?

Comment: Vacuum will not stop radio waves; otherwise, how would space satellites transmit to and from the Earth? Glass should also not interfere unless it is metal film coated. As to if the module will work in a vacuum, I don't see why not but I'll leave that to be definitely answered.

Comment: Pressure differences *can* do weird things to MEMS oscillators, so if the NRF24L01 (whatever that is; please link a datasheet) or the Arduino use MEMS oscillators you might have an issue. If it's a metal vacuum chamber you'll have a hard time getting radio waves through it, but the vacuum itself isn't the issue--just the metal case.

Comment: Vacuum means that there's no air to convect, so all cooling will be via conduction and radiation. Probably not an issue for low power electronics, but beware hotspots and high power components.

Comment: It depends, is the module made of components that each can handle a vacuum? I don't think the problem is data transmission itself, it's about will the components of your modules such as ICs, capacitors, canned crystals, batteries etc what you intend to put into vacuum can handle the vacuum.

Comment: How much vacuum? There might be something on the PCB or components that outgasses for a while.

Comment: Why would you put hobbyist electronics inside a vacuum chamber though? Strange combination.

Comment: I have no experience with vacuum chambers, but isn’t there a possibility of physical issues, e.g components “sucked out” of the PCB if the soldering is too flimsy? That would probably be more during the “emptying” phase rather than in steady state, though. Some components probably have a range of acceptable pressure (like they have for temperature, humidity, or vibration).

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the details of your vacuum environment, so it is very hard to give a precise answer.  However there are three main strands to consider:

- Will the device/module impact your ability to achieve your desired vacuum level?
- Will the device/module function in the vacuum?
- Will the signal penetrate your vacuum enclosure?

**Vacuum contamination**
It really depends on the level of vacuum you are seeking.  At single digit millibars, almost certainly no issue.  At UHV levels, the outgassing from the FR4 laminate may prevent you ever reaching the target levels unless you have massive pumping rates. Similarly the module may not survive the bakeouts typically used during initial pumpdown.

**Module operation**
In terms of whether the device will function, the biggest concern is probably heat dissipation.  In normal use, convective cooling is typically the dominant mode of heat loss, and all the parts will be speced assuming they have at least basic convective cooling.  Place the module in a vacuum, and it may simply overheat.

If you are including things like LiPo battery packs, you may find they swell/burst under a vacuum, but again mileage will vary.

**Signal transmission**
Assuming the glass windows are not coated with a metallic film, and they are multiple wavelengths in size, the signal should propagate fine.

Having said all of that, if the module is cheap, and contamination of the vacuum chamber is not a concern, just give it a go!